# storing data from .txt as column vectors in c++

Tags: c++, ifstream, cin

My input .txt looks as follows:

```
6 3
0 1 5
0 2 1
0 5 53
```

From the second line onwards I want to store the columns in arrays, so I did the following:

```
main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::ifstream infile("instance1.txt");

    int NumOne, NumTwo;

    if (infile.good()){
        infile >> NumOne >> NumTwo;
    }

    int Array1[NumTwo];
    int Array2[NumTwo];
    int Array3[NumTwo];

    for(int i = 1; i < NumTwo + 1; i++){
        infile >> Array1[i-1] >> Array2[i-1] >> Array3[i-1];
    }

    infile.close();
    cout<<"first number"<<NumOne<<endl;
    cout<<"second number"<<NumTwo<<endl;

    for (int i=0; i < sizeof(Array1); i++){
        cout << Array1[i] << " " << Array2[i] << " " << Array3[i] << endl;
    }
    cout<<"first array"<<Array1<<endl;
    cout<<"second array"<< Array2<<endl;
    cout<<"third array"<< Array3<<endl;
}
```

My output is the following:

```
first number6
second number5
0 1606413088 0
0 1 5
0 2 1
0 5 53
6923 5 1606414340
1 0 32767
1606673872 0 1606413088
32767 0 1
1606594089 0 2
32767 0 5
0 1 4
65793 2 5
80256 6923 5
0 1 0
80256 1606673872 0
0 32767 0
17623816 1606594089 0
1 32767 0
first array10x7fff5fbfeb10
second array20x7fff5fbfeaf0
third array0x7fff5fbfead0
```

Does anyone know where these numbers come from? I'm new to C++ and appreciate any hints about what goes wrong here.

Comment: `int Array1[NumOne];`  This line and lines like this are not valid ANSI C++.  You must declare arrays using a constant expression denoting the number of elements, not a runtime value.  Also what is the value of `sizeof(Array1)`?  Instead, use `std::vector` and the `std::vector::size()` function to determine the number of elements.

Comment: What is it exactly you expect `cout<<"first array"<<Array1<<endl;` to do? `Array1` is a pointer, so it prints out the memory location of the pointer.

Comment: NumOne is 6, so read 6 lines of your file but it has only 3

Comment: I see many things go wrong here, I adapted the code. However I only know the size of my array from NumTwo. How can I solve this then?

Comment: do you know vectors? consider it same as arrays but can be resized or declared without an initial size

Comment: @steph  -- In C++, dynamic arrays are done by using `std::vector`.  Arrays in standard C++ are fixed in sixe -- they cannot be resized, or have their sizes determined at runtime.

Comment: This number won't change during runtime that's why I thought this might be possible.

Comment: @steph - You declared **variable**s to store the size value.  Note the emphasis on the word *variable*.  That's all the compiler cares about.  If it were a constant, then that would be a different story.  `const int NumOne = 10;` for example would be ok, since it is a compile-time value.  In addition, you're reading in the value for `NumOne` and `NumTwo`.  That is considered a value determined at runtime.

Comment: Yes, it makes completely sense. Thanks!

Comment: Instead of checking if infile is good only before reading the first two numbers you should check if it is bad (and terminate).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure how this code already compiled but:
**Issue One:**

```
cout<<"first array"<<Array1<<endl;
cout<<"second array"<< Array2<<endl;
cout<<"third array"<< Array3<<endl;
```

I think this will display the hexadecimal address of each array, since you didn't type which element `Array[?]` in every array you are tying to display.

**Issue Two:**

```
    for(int i = 1; i < NumOne + 1; i++){
    infile >> Array1[i-1] >> Array2[i-1] >> Array3[i-1];
```

This code will set junk data, since it's going to try reading NumOne + 1 means 6 + 1 = 7 lines as max while you only have 3 lines. So what are you trying to do here?

**Issue Three:**
 you need to set a fixed size before declaring any array. So `int Numone = ?` or `Array[?]`

Try this part of using vectors if you need to set the size of your container *during* run time

```
        #include <vectors>
        #include <iostream>
        int main(int argc, char** argv)
        {
            std::ifstream infile("instance1.txt");

        int NumOne, NumTwo;

        if (infile.good()){
            infile >> NumOne >> NumTwo;
        }

        std::vector<int> MyVectorOne(NumTwo);
        std::vector<int> MyVectorTwo(NumTwo);
        std::vector<int> MyVectorThree(NumTwo);

        for(int i = 1; i < NumTwo + 1; i++){ // again this is wrong. What do you want here??
            infile >> MyVectorOne[i-1] >> MyVectorOne[i-1] >> MyVectorOne[i-1];
        }

        infile.close();
        cout<<"first number"<<NumOne<<endl;
        cout<<"second number"<<NumTwo<<endl;

        for (int i=0; i < MyVectorOne.size(); i++){
            cout << MyVectorOne[i] << " " << MyVectorTwo[i] << " " << MyVectorThree[i] << endl;
        }

     // and here? what are you trying to display? this is also wrong
        cout<<"first array"<< MyVectorOne<<endl;
        cout<<"second array"<< MyVectorTwo<<endl;
        cout<<"third array"<< MyVectorThree<<endl;

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: There are other issues, such as 1) missing the return type when declaring `main`, and 2) Using non-standard C++ Variable Length Arrays.

Comment: in the first for-loop I want to store the first number in the first array, the second number in the second array and the third number in the third array and this for all rows (except the first)

Comment: okay, you read two numbers already in if (!inFile.good()). so you want 0 in the first, 1 in the second and 5 in the third? and so on till the end of file?